# Towers of Hanoi - Bellman equation solution

Tags: algorithm, towers-of-hanoi

I have to implement an algorithm that solves the Towers of Hanoi game for k pods and d rings in a limited number of moves (let's say 4 pods, 10 rings, 50 moves for example) using Bellman dynamic programming equation (if the problem is solvable of course).

Now, I understand the logic behind the equation:

[image: Bellman equation - discrete time]

where V^T is the objective function at time T, a^0 is the action at time 0, x^0 is the starting configuration, H_0 is cumulative gain f(x^0, a^0)=x^1.

The cardinality of the state space is $k^d$ and I get that a good representation for a state is a number in base k: d digits that can go from 0 to k-1. Each digit represents a ring and the digit can go from 0 to k-1, that are the labels of the k rings.

I want to minimize the number of moves for going from the initial configuration (10 rings on the first pod) to the end one (10 rings on the last pod).

What I don't get is: how do I write my objective function?

Comment: I was unaware that there is a generalization with more than 3 pods; how would more than 3 pods make the problem easier to solve (in the sense that less moves are necessary)? Are less moves necessary with more pods?

Comment: What do you mean? You said yourself that the objective function was V^t… (well more precisely this is the value function).

Comment: @Codor: If there are d rings and k >= d+1 pods, you can solve it in 2d moves: just put each ring on a different pod (d moves), and then move them all back into their final position (d moves).  I think that with fewer pods there would be solutions taking an intermediate amount of time.

Comment: I have to say I don't understand the equation, and I use DP quite a lot...  Also I'm aware that Bellman invented DP.

Comment: I think I poorly stated the question: this algorithm should find the optimal number of moves to get from the initial state to the end one, if it can be done in less than n moves. I think is a recursion on a tree, but I've never done an algorithm course before. Btw the teacher will show the algorithm tomorrow and I will post it here, if anyone gets the solution :)

Comment: So you understand how the equation works and what it computes but you want to know how you can actually compute it?

Comment: I think what I don't understand is how to represent the state at T-1. The state T is a vector of ten 3s, in the case 4 pods (enumerated form 0 to 3) and 10 rings. The state is a vector of 0s. But how to pass from x^T to x^{T-1}?

Answer (score 1):

The first you need to do is choose a reward function H_t(s,a) which will define you goal. Once this function is chosen, the (optimal) value function is defined and all you have to do is compute it.

The idea of dynamic programming for the Bellman equation is that you should compute V_t(s) bottom-up: you start with t=T, then t=T-1 and so on until t=0.

The initial case is simply given by:

```
V_T(s) = 0, ∀s
```

You can compute V_{T-1}(x) ∀x from V_T:

```
V_{T-1}(x) = max_a [ H_{T-1}(x,a) ]
```

Then you can compute V_{T-2}(x) ∀s from V_{T-1}:

```
V_{T-2}(x) = max_a [ H_{T-2}(x,a) + V_{T-1}(f(x,a)) ]
```

And you keep on computing V_{t-1}(x) ∀s from V_{t}:

```
V_{t-1}(x) = max_a [ H_{t-1}(x,a) + V_{t}(f(x,a)) ]
```

until you reach V_0.

Which gives the algorithm:

```
forall x:
  V[T](x) ← 0
for t from T-1 to 0:
  forall x:
    V[t](x) ← max_a { H[t](x,a) + V[t-1](f(x,a)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

What actually was requested was this:

```
def k_hanoi(npods,nrings):
    if  nrings == 1 and npods > 1: #one remaining ring: just one move 
        return 1
    if npods == 3:
        return 2**nrings - 1 #optimal solution with 3 pods take 2^d -1 moves
    if npods > 3 and nrings > 0:
        sol = []
        for pivot in xrange(1, nrings): #loop on all possible pivots
            sol.append(2*k_hanoi(npods, pivot)+k_hanoi(npods-1, nrings-pivot))
        return min(sol) #minimization on pivot


k = 4
d = 10

print k_hanoi(k, d)
```

I think it is the Frame algorithm, with optimization on the pivot chosen to divide the disks in two subgroups. I also think someone demonstrated this is optimal for 4 pegs (in 2014 or something like that? Not sure btw) and conjectured to be optimal for more than 4 pegs. The limitation on the number of moves can be implemented easily.

The value function in this case was the number of steps needed to go from the initial configuration to the ending one and it needed be minimized. Thank you all for the contribution.